# Buffer tool issue in QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis-3, buffer

When I use Buffer tool. Distance is in geographic degrees. And it suggests me `"Consider reprojecting to a projected local coordinate system for accurate results"`
I try to change map unit in "Project properties" >> "General setting". But I still got that problem. I also try to save as another project, still not work.

My project is WGS 84: EPSG:4326.

Anyone have same problem or know how to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. The tools care about the CRS of your layer, so save it to a different file and change the CRS when doing so. 2. The measurement units are only relevant for the measurement tool. 3. The Coordnate display units are only relevant for the small display at the bottom of your map window.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export your layer to a local CRS (Right click on layer, export as ...) UTM might be a good choice. Load the layer to your project and now the buffer tool should work without that warning

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really helpful